# Qual a diferença do vue para o vue-cli

Tags: vue.js

Qual a diferença entre o VUE.JS para o VUE-cli. Há alguma diferença? Eu sinceramente não consegui encontrar a diferença.

Comment: O Vue.JS é um **framework**, enquanto o Vue CLI é uma ferramenta para a criação de novas aplicações que usam o framework Vue. São duas _coisas_ completamente diferentes.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode ajudar, o CLI significa _Command Line Interface_ que, em pt-BR, Interface de Linha de Comando. São comandos executados a partir de um terminal, que podem, por exemplo, criar um componente (com todos os arquivos necessários e o código base) criar o build de produção, criar um servidor local para teste, etc

Answer (score 7):

O vue-cli é uma ferramenta para gerar aplicações/projetos. Correr o `vue-cli` vai pedir-te para escolheres ferramentas para usar no projecto que o `vue-cli` vai criar, e dependendo do que escolhes ficas com uma estrutura de diretorios completa, tudo configurado e pronto para desenvolver a aplicação Vue.js.

Vue.js é uma biblioteca de JavaScript, (quase) uma linguagem <sup>(*)</sup> com que o projeto é feito, o `vue-cli` acelera os passos necessários para poderes programar em Vus/JavaScript. Para usar o Vue.js não precisas de usar o vue-cli, mas ajuda pois evita teres de configurar compilador, verificadores de código (ESLint), dependências e decidir estruturas de pastas.

<sup>(*)</sup> - Vue.js não é proriamente uma linguagem, é uma biblioteca feita em JavaScript, mas permite usar no mesmo ficheiro sintaxe parecida com HTML (mustache), CSS e JavaScript. É uma biblioteca escrita em JavaScript, com uma maneira de programagar e organizar própria e mecanismos de reactividade próprios.

Answer (score 5):

VueJS é uma framework front-end que facilita e acelera o desenvolvimento para aplicações web, ela é escrita em Javascript e tem uma ótima comunidade.

Vue CLI é uma ferramenta de linha de comando feita pela comunidade do Vue para facilitar ainda mais a inicialização de uma nova aplicação Vue, com ela podemos gerar nossa aplicação a partir de templates oficiais (incluindo integração com webpack, etc), diminuindo o tempo de configuração de ambiente.

[Fonte](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/criando-um-projeto-vuejs-com-o-vuecli-e-webstorm-58b695339c01)